# How to set left gap between custom cell and its content view to 0 in tableView

Tags: swift

I've noticed a little gap in between custom cell and its content in "Debug View Hierarchy".

[image: cell gap]

I want to make it disappear, but can't.

I did:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    table.separatorStyle = .none
    table.separatorInset = .zero
    table.contentInset = .zero
    ...
}
```

and this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
    cell.separatorInset = .zero
    cell.contentView.layoutMargins = .zero
    cell.layoutMargins = .zero
    ...
}
```

The only way I could, was the answer from stack overflow which recommended to set tableView leading constraint <-> safe area to -15. Yeah, that works, but men, it can't be right solution.

What do you guys think?

Comment: if it is custom cell set label constraints inside your XIB

Comment: Do you only want to set the leading position or both leading and trailing as well?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, it's not the case, I set my leading constraint to 0, but this gap is like between custom cell and table, not custom cell and its subview.

Comment: @Pancho, I want to get rid of left gap and right gap, to be able to set it on my own, with my constraints.